# How can I set what encoding must be used by a site?

Tags: php, encoding

On some systems it is UTF-8, on others latin-1. How do you set this? Is it something in php.ini?

(I know you can set the encoding/charset for a given page by setting HTTP headers, but this is not what I am looking for.)

Alex

Comment: If you're not looking for encoding/charset, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default_charset setting in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the character set of non php files you can tell apache what to use.
AddDefaultCharset utf-8